# The query specified in the URI is not valid + Projection + LINQ Select

Tags: linq, asp.net-web-api, odata, projection

I apologize if this is a repetitive question. Basically what I am trying to achieve is to have my projection is a separate method/class which I can reuse like this (keep in mind I am beginner with LINQ).

```
public static Expression<Func<MyObject, object>> getProjection()
    {
        return r => new
        {
            Name = r.Name,
            Address = r.Address,
            City = r.City,
            PostalCode = r.PostalCode,
            Province = r.Province,
            Country = r.Country,
            Phone = r.Phone,
            Website = r.Website
        };
    }
```

However, when I call Projection like this.

```
var filteredList = db.MyObject.Select(Projections.getProjection()).AsQueryable();
return Ok(filteredList);
```

Then I get the error

> The query specified in the URI is not valid. Could not find a property
>   named 'Name' on type 'System.Object'.

If I replace the Projection helper method with actual Projection just by copy and pasting then it works. I am just trying to avoid rewriting the same projection again for other Select methods by creating a helper method "getProjection". First if you can verify if this is the right way of calling Projection. Secondly how can I get rid of that OData error.

Thanks

Comment: If you will return strongly-typed items instead of object - will it result in same error? Maybe the OData is confused about dynamic objects. And my second assumption - maybe the evaluation of query is needed - try to call ToList() after Select statement (db.MyObject.Select(Projections.getProjection()).ToList().AsQueryable())

Comment: @n.piskunov thanks for the reply. I tried strongly-typed but I still got the same error. Then I tried your second suggestion and then I got a different error. See below.

(Projections.getProjection()).ToList().AsQueryable() =  {"The entity or complex type 'Sample.DataContexts.MyObject' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query."}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LINQ to Entities needs strong types. They can be generic, and the CAN be anonymous. Your problem is that your function returns a weak type Expression>.

Use a strong type to solve this, or don't use a projection method.

A: Strong type. This is actually quite tidy, and *could* be considered *lazy* to try and get away with an anonymous type here.

```
public class MyRecord { /* fields here */ }
public static Expression<Func<MyObject, MyRecord>> getProjection()
{
    return r => new MyRecord
    {
        Name = r.Name,
        Address = r.Address,
        City = r.City,
        PostalCode = r.PostalCode,
        Province = r.Province,
        Country = r.Country,
        Phone = r.Phone,
        Website = r.Website
    };
}

/* of type IQueryable<MyRecord> */
var filteredList = db.MyObject.Select(getProjection());
```

B: Remove the projection method:

```
/* of type IQueryable<Anonymous> - this is why 'var' exists */
var filteredList = db.MyObject.Select(r => new
{
    Name = r.Name,
    Address = r.Address,
    City = r.City,
    PostalCode = r.PostalCode,
    Province = r.Province,
    Country = r.Country,
    Phone = r.Phone,
    Website = r.Website
});
```

Note this if you intend to return this to another method, you're still going to need a strong (non-anonymous) type. The only way you can pass anonymous types through methods is via generics. e.g:

```
function T Do<T>(func<T> something) { return something(); }
var anon = Do(() => { a = 1, b = 2 });
```

C: If you do this projection often AND you DON'T want to create projection classes then ask yourself 'why not?'. If you want to avoid writing this project code often and are happy to create projection classes then consider using a tool such as [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/). It's use is pretty common nowadays.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried your suggestion and it did work. I accepted your answer. However, I am unsure what you mean by "The only way you can pass anonymous types through methods is via generics"

Comment: @programmerboy The compiler works with strong types only (CLR, DLR is for another day). So each method needs to know what's coming in and what's going out. You cannot define a method as `function anonymous MyFunction(anonymous myParam);`. But you can define a method as `function T MyFunction<T>(T myParam);`. T in this case is not anonymous, it is generic. But T can be an anonymous type if used like so: `var output = MyFunction(new { a = 'b' });`. The return type is the same as the input type and the compiler can infer the type from the input parameter.

Comment: @programmerboy Do bear in mind that anonymous types are not dynamic types. They are created at compile time, not runtime. The compiler is just creating them for you so you don't have to write the code yourself and have lots of tiny classes cluttering up your solution.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Can you give practical example of the function similar to what you did for other two? You can edit the answer.

Comment: @programmerboy The LINQ `Select` method is an example of this. When you send your lambda expression `selector` to the `Select` function, you are providing it with an anonymous type. This is the generic `TResult` as defined by `Select`. The function has no understanding of `TResult` and cares not if it's a user defined type or an anonymous type.

Answer (score 0):

So, what if you will try to use simple method instead of expression?

E.g. :

```
public static object GetProjection(MyObject o){
    return new{
            Name = o.Name,
            Address = o.Address,
            City = o.City,
            PostalCode = o.PostalCode,
            Province = o.Province,
            Country = o.Country,
            Phone = o.Phone,
            Website = o.Website
    };
}
```

And then in your controller:

```
var filteredList = db.MyObject.Select(GetProjection).AsQueryable();
return Ok(filteredList);
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but I cannot even compile due to this error.

The type arguments for method 'Queryable.Select<TSource, TResult>(IQueryable<TSource>, Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly/

Comment: Where does this error occur? What is the return type of your controller? Provide please the source code of you controller action